# Web scraping python selenium en una ventana activa de chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, scraping, google-chrome

necesito obtener datos de una pagina la cual tiene varios procesos para entrar incluyendo un captcha, antes lo venia realizando con AppleScript entraba manualmente a la pagina de la cual necesitaba tomar los datos, ahora lo quiero hacer con Python.

mi pregunta se como puedo iniciar el scraping en una ventana activa sin necesidad de hacer todo el proceso para entrar

Gracias

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/xxxx/Python/drivers/chromedriver')
browser.get()





browser.find_element_by_id("cph_columna_gen_txtNoSolicitud").send_keys("15975576")
```

Comment: Una página con captcha es señal de que **no** quiere que llegues directo a ella.